# Absolute div no overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, positioning, absolute

I have two divs:

```
#container{
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Inside this container I have another div:

```
#image{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left-200px;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    background-image:url('images/image.png');
    left:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

When I resize my window to a very small viewport, the full image cannot be displayed. The user is able to scroll to the right. How can I prevent that?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to add `overflow:hidden` to `#container`?

Comment: typo? margin-left-200px;

Comment: @Vucko, yes, I but it's not working

Comment: @Jordy how about adding `overflow` to `html,body` - [Examlpe](http://jsfiddle.net/dCss6/)?

Comment: @Vucko, Not working. Indeed the scroll bar is not visible, but I'm still able to scroll to the right with my mousewheel.

Comment: @Jordy [make a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your CSS:

```
html {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here is working jsfidde: http://jsfiddle.net/5tDbx/

Comment: Not working. Indeed the scroll bar is not visible, but I'm still able to scroll to the right with my mousewheel.